# Hide a minus symbol from a word mailmerge field

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have a word document that is using mergefields supplied by an external system so have linked a datasource to provide the mergefields.

One of the mergefields required shows a balance but it pulls through onto the document with a minus figure eg. -£10.00. This is technically correct on the external system as there is a credit but the document we are sending is for a refund so it currently reads as, "please find enclosed payment of -£10.00" which doesn't quite look right!

Is there a way I can hide the minus symbol? I looked at an if then else statement but can't see an obvious way of doing it?
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using numeric picture formats defined for merge fields. Follow these steps:

1. Select merge field on document
2. Press `Shift + F9` to switch to field coding. You would see something like `{MERGEFIELD MyData}`.
3. Edit merge filed like this `{MERGEFIELD MyData \# "0.00;0.00"}` Here `\#` is switch for numeric formatting. `"0.00;0.00"` is formatting for positive and negative numbers (separated by `;`).
4. Press `F9` to update merge field.

You should now see positive numbers instead of negative. `0.00` can be changed per your need.